# How to add at least two decimal digits with siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to create a good `\EUR` command that displays the value according to DIN5008 with `.` as thousand separator and `,` as decimal point and at least two decimal places.
However, if there are more decimal places given then more should be shown.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[detect-all, separate-uncertainty]{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 4, group-separator = {~}, locale=DE}

\RequirePackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\EUR}[1]{
    \num[group-separator = {.}, round-precision = 2, round-mode = places]{#1}~\unit{€}\xspace}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=5.2]r}
        Description A & 123 & \EUR{1234.5678}\\
        Description B & 1.2 & \EUR{12.3}\\
        Description C & 12.3 & \EUR{123}\\
        Description D & 12.34 & \EUR{12345.678901}\\
        Description E & 12345 & \EUR{12345678.9}\\      
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

I was only able to round to fixed 2 digits but not to not round at all but just show at least 2 decimal digits (even if less are provided) and more if more are provided... Can this be done?

Comment: What do you think is the purpose of `\xspace` at the end of `\EUR`? I know that it does *exactly nothing useful*. Remove it.

Comment: Off-topic: The option `detect=all` is a hold-over from an earlier version of the `siunitx` package. The modern option is `mode=text`.

Comment: Please clarify the purpose of the "if there are more decimal places given then more should be shown" objective. E.g., should this criterion be applied to the `\EUR` macro directly? Or just to the middle column of the `tabular` environment?

Comment: @Mico: ideally to to \EUR macro directly.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the hint with mode=text.

Comment: @egreg: it does prevent more spaces if used in normal text flow. I also do not get it since it only should add an extra space if necessary but it definitely has an effect!

Comment: @mrCarnivore No, try with and without it. The only possible use of `\xspace` is at the end of commands with *no* argument, but it's not guaranteed to work always.

Comment: @Mico: `mode-text` does not work with `\textbf` for numbers. Is there another alternative that works instead of `detect=all`?

Comment: @mrCarnivore - To enable **bolding**, I would change `mode = text,` to `mode = text, reset-text-series = false,`. See p. 19 of the user guide of the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package for more information.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks. That works! However, what is the advantage of using this instead of `detect=all`? That seems less commands to do everything...

Comment: @mrCarnivore - The author and maintainer of the `siunitx` package has announced that support for the `detect=...` route will go away one day. It's barely on life-support at the moment... For sure, the `detect=...` approach is not mentioned with a single word in the user guide of the current version (= v.3.2.4) of the package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I revised this answer after receiving additional information from the OP. I revised it further after realizing that the answer should focus just on the properties of the `\EUR` macro -- and thus also ignore the `tabular` stuff shown in the OP's code.)

In the definition of the `\EUR` macro, you need to replace

```
round-precision = 2, round-mode = places
```

with

```
minimum-decimal-digits=2
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode=text, %detect-all, 
         separate-uncertainty,
         group-minimum-digits = 4, 
         group-separator = {\,},
         locale=DE}

\newcommand{\EUR}[1]{%
   \num[group-separator = {.}, minimum-decimal-digits=2]{#1}\,\unit{€}}

\begin{document}
\EUR{123}

\EUR{123.45}

\EUR{12345.678912}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I want more (!) decimal digits than two if more are provided and not only two. Only if less are provided I want it extended to two…

Comment: @mrCarnivore - please see the revised answer.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I was a little confused at first since you applied it to the numbers on the left and not the euro amounts but now I get it. Thanks!

Comment: @mrCarnivore - I've modified my answer again, to make it just about the properties of the `\EUR` macro -- since that is what the core of your posting is about, right?

Comment: Thank you. That helps.